# W3C Web SQL Database transaction function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, transactions, web-sql

My question is based on W3C Web SQL Database. I am trying to populate SQL with the data I am getting from API. Here is my code

```
     var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    for(i=0;i<data.responseMsg.length;i++){ 
    var assignid_check = data.responseMsg[i].assignId;//------->3
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);//------->4
    function errorCB(tx, err) 
    {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }
    function queryDB(tx) 
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table_assign WHERE assign_id='+assignid_check, [],     querySuccess, errorCB);
}
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;                              
    if(len>0) //if exist  jump to next array
    {
    alert("exist");
    }   
    else  //if not exist insert
    {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO table_assign (audit_id,assign_id) VALUES (1,'+assignid_check+')'); 
    alert("not exist");
    }               
    }           
    }
```

Here problem is in line number 3 after getting "assignid_check" value I am calling transaction method. After transaction method I just want to call callback function i.e queryDB(tx) and if there is any error I want errorCB(tx,results) to get called. But soon after line 3 gets executed line 4 will execute and then again in for loop I value will get incremented and then it will execute line 3 and then 4. Only for the last value i.e only for last I value transaction will call queryDB(tx) callback function.

I am doing this for a phonegap application. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but looping transaction is wrong usage.

Comment: @KyawTun: sorry for delay, Well i got my desired result by making use of foreach loop, Still i dont know why it was not working when i used for loop. And why we are not supposed to carry looping on transaction?